# Cambiar la ruta de guardado de imágenes en el servidor

Tags: php, linux

Realicé un formulario para subir imágenes al servidor pero en lugar de que me guarde la imagen en `var/www/html/mi proyecto` lo puse en `/home/imagenes`.

El detalle esta que al momento de visualizar la imagen no me la muestra, el proyecto esta en Linux.

`2.- echo "<td><img src=\"/var/www/html/../../../../../../home/documentos_enlinea/".$rs['baucher']."\" 3.-  width='500' height='500'/></td>"."</tr>";`

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español, mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Recuerda colocar tu código y el error en el texto de la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Si la imagen está fuera de la ruta pública no la vas a poder mostrar directamente con una etiqueta `<img />`

Comment: cambia la ruta donde se guardan los ficheros para que sea /var/www. De lo contrario, el servidor no podrá "ver" todos estos datos

Comment: 'triby pero si hay alguna manera de poder visualizarla??'